# Magento Default Order By select list ignoring my admin settings

Tags: sorting, magento

I am using Magento 1.4.0.1.

I am trying to get my product listing pages to display products listed by SKU by default.
I have SKU appearing in the select list - I added it via the Manage Attributes admin area.
I have then set SKU as the Default Sort Option in System > Configuration > Catalog > Product listing sort by.

All of my categories in the admin are set to use Config Settings in the Display Settings tab, and the Default Product Listing Sort by list is greyed out (although it defaults the value shown in the list to Best Value??? - Best Value apparently translates to Position on the front-end in Magento 1.4.0.1??).

Those settings should work, but they don't.
I must assume that the template code somewhere is overriding the admin settings, but I have trudged through some places looking for something wrong and found nothing. I might not be looking in the right places of course!

I have also tried specifically setting a category to default to SKU display, and not use the config settings. This didn't change anything either.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be overriding this - and where to find it to resolve it?

Help much appreciated!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see if the default value is overridden somewhere.
It could be:

- in a category view => Manage categories => Display Settings of the desired category;
- in a store view => same where you set the default ordering, selecting a different store wit the dropdown menu (top-left corner of Configuration => Catalog => Frontend);
- in the layout file => this could be in your catalog.xml or in a custom layout update;

Comment: Where would I look to find this out please?

Comment: Thanks mate. It's definitely not 1 or 2, so I will carefully check 3. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks - I've ticked the answer as I think it has to be option 3 - somewhere... It's not 1 or 2. One thing that puzzles me is looknig at the category in admin, with the "use config" checkbox ticked, the value in the disabled select list says "Best Value". Hopefully that's not picking up the actual default value, just the first in the now disabled list?

Comment: if you want to manually force the sort direction from XML layout, put <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action> in the catalog/product_list_toolbar block